# Free firewall and network monitor Application like the LittleSnitch?

Tags: network, software-recommendation, firewall

I am searching for a good free firewall and network monitor as the littlesnitch but I can't pay for this app.
I want a firewall that will protect me but more of that to monitor any connection in or out of my mac so that to check if any malicious connections are establishing from or to my mac.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That would be the [TCPblock](http://tcpblock.wordpress.com/).

Almost like Little snitch but no fancy UI.

TCPBlock is a lightweight and fast application firewall for Mac OS X 10.6 or later developed by delantis.com.
The Mac OS X firewall protects you from connections that come from outside of your computer. But what about the software from your computer that opens new connections to the internet? With TCPBlock you can prevent selected applications on your computer from opening connections to the network.

Comment: Thank you. This app is not from identifier developer it is safe to use it? It needs installation and root permissions and I am afraid of these applications with this permissions and from an unidentified developer.

Comment: I understand, but there is nothing that is 100% safe, and I uses it and did not notice anything.

Comment: Cheers anyway. May I will try to buy the little-snitch which is more safe at some point.